# yii - form/modal based on mongodb

Tags: model-view-controller, mongodb, yii

I am using mongo db in my yii project.

I am newbie in yii and mvc. I need to show some fields from database to user. And also allow them to edit those fields when they click `edit`. From what I know so far, I need a modal to create form. Modal should extend `CActiveRecord` (because I am allowing edit).

But I have no clue how this is going to work with mongodb ? Its very differnt from mysql (structure and fields are not definite in mongodb). Some users have field (column) `abc` while some do user do not have it.

I am looked into the mongodbsuite for yii. But its very hard for me to understand that at this level.

I am willing to write my own custom code, if someone can give me a direction. (or I'll have to write my own code destroying the feel of yii/mvc. Fetching everything and inserting into textboxes and then allow users to edit those)

Comment: Why -1 in my 3 questions at the same time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this extension will help you. Pls check - [YIIMongoDBSuite](http://canni.github.com/YiiMongoDbSuite/xhtml_single/index.html)

Comment: Yes, finally I used this extension. I should have given my own answer.

Comment: You may also want to look into this version of the suite, which has had updates and fixes compared to the original (now unmaintained).

https://github.com/digitick/yii-mongodb-suite

Answer (score -1):

What i suggest instead of writing your own code and doing testing to make it work, it is always better to shift to mysql,oracle or anything that Yii supports. it would save life

Yii Supports

1. SQLite
2. mysql
3. PostgreSQL
4. SQL Server
5. Oracle

Comment: but have you looked into mongodb ?
Its actually what I need for my needs. I am dealing with facebook/linkedin json data.

Comment: to be honest i have not seen that but you can tackle `CJson` in yii to tackle facebook data

Comment: If you havent you should. Its a great. Also, I am concerned about storing inconsistent (columns/fields are not fixed) data into db. So, I am using mongo.

Answer (score -1):

It might be worth asking this question on the yiiframework forum
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/
where there seem to be people actively using yii and mongodb.

Comment: Is this the answer ? btw I have asked there too.